# Is it irony? What's the word?

Tags: single-word-requests, irony

What is the word for doing something where said thing is a protest against what you are doing?

Example, posting a facebook status that pokes fun at people copying and pasting statuses and sharing them however by posting this status you're doing the very thing you're speaking against.

Comment: I'd say such a post is [***ironically self-referential***.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ironically+self-referential&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) Arguably ***hypocritical***.

Comment: Potentially a type of [reductio ad absurdum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reductio_ad_absurdum), but that isn't an exact match (raa can refer to other things, and I'm not sure all such posts would be raa).

Comment: The result is sarcasm, by meaning the opposite of your words or actions. If you thought you did mean it, but the result reveals the BS, that's hyprocracy @FumbleFingers.

Comment: @StuartF This idea of yours is wholly misleading: "reductio ad absurdum", which has been used a lot as a synonym of the modern "[proof by contradiction](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/reductio_ad_absurdum)", is strictly a principle of logic, and subsequently, a method. It asserts that if  assuming the truth (falsity) of a statement leads logically to the contradiction of a known truth, then the assumption is wrong and the contrary can be accepted as true. The question raised by the OP has to do only with  (some type of) deceitful behaviour and moral principles.

Comment: Very similar: [What's an idiom to express the idea that the correcter stands corrected?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/528016/whats-an-idiom-to-express-the-idea-the-correcter-stands-corrected/528118#528118) Being _hoist with/by/on one’s own petard_ is a suitable metaphor. Also [word or longer expression to describe someone behaving the way they are accusing others of doing](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/461240/word-or-longer-expression-to-describe-someone-behaving-the-way-they-are-accusing/461243#461243).

Comment: John Selden's Table-Talk (c. 1654): *Preachers say, 'Do as I say, not as I do*. Gospel of Luke 6, 41 : *You see the mote in your brother's eye, but you do not see the beam in your own eye*.

Comment: Rather *impudence* or *offhandedness* than irony.

Comment: Attention-seeking?

Answer (score 1):

[Irony](https://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=irony) is quite suitable :

> Incongruity between what might be expected and what actually occurs

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/irony) gives :

> Incongruity between the actual result of a sequence of events and the normal or expected result
> Humorous or sardonic literary style or form characterized by irony

My Alternative is [Antithetic/Antithesis](https://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=antithetic) :

> Sharply contrasted in character or purpose

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/antithetic) gives :

> Being in direct and unequivocal opposition
> Directly opposite or opposed

**Discussion :**

In grammar & style rule books , we see the Stylist say something like "DO NOT USE ALL-CAPS" & "Do not over-use Exclamations !!!!" & Etc , where the Stylist is going against the rule. It is not that the Stylist is unaware : It is to highlight the Impact of the rule. It is a rhetorical device to try going against (opposite to) what the rule is claiming.
We can use Irony & Antithetic/Antithesis when going against the necessary claim.
We can avoid that by going with the necessary claim like this : "Do not use all-caps" & "Do not over-use Exclamations" & Etc.
Situation in your Case is Copy-Pasting "Do not Copy-Paste Statuses & Messages" Messages.

Comment: I hadn't thought of the deliberate, pragmatic usage (to reinforce the rule), and I'm not sure OP had. But a valuable addition to the discussion.

Comment: I think , "unironic/unironically" might work too , @EdwinAshworth , when the action was not entirely unintentional , though there may be a change in meaning !